# Using Align inside of ListView to align Widgets left/right

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-listview

My application shows profile of users. A feature I wish to add is to allow "like"ing of profiles by users. For this, I am using a [Listview](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html) to show all profile content.

**The problem** is when adding a [LikeButton](https://pub.dev/packages/like_button), it gets centered, which is expected. I want to move it to the (top) right.

[Align](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Align-class.html) appears like a more viable and elegant solution that doing something like this (see below) but I cannot get `Align` it to work (it remains centered).

```
ListView(
  children: [
    Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
      children: [LikeButton()],
    ),
    // rest of profile information
```

Using a `Container` with `width: double.infinity` doesn't work with `Align` either - it remains centered.

```
Container(
  width: double.infinity,
  child: Align(
    alignment: Alignment.topRight,
    child: LikeButton(),
  ),
)
```

Is using a [Row](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Row-class.html) my only option or is there a better way?

Comment: Add code for LikeButton widget

Comment: @JonathanIxcayau see https://pub.dev/packages/like_button#how-to-use-it

Comment: Try adding LikeButton inside Container with custom width, and then Align widget as Parent

Comment: @CybeX accept my answer if you found it helpful

Answer (score 2):

Since LikeButton is a Row or Column it self, You can't Align it like that,

You can use its properties to align it

```
ListView(
        children: [
            LikeButton(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            )
          ],
)
```

or just wrap it inside a SizedBox and align that box

```
Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          height: 500,
          alignment: Alignment.topRight,
          child: SizedBox(
                width: 100,
                height: 100,
                child: LikeButton()),
)
```

- Row takes the size of its children so your first code won't align it vertically
- You didn't give height in you're Container code so Aligning it by topRight would be meaningless

Answer (score 0):

You can `Stack` the `LikeButton()` onto `Container(child:Row())` and position it to top right by giving values to `topRight` parameters.